# fiware-orion NGSIv2 update context

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I created a small stack using with orion and the populated mongodb from the tour guide app.

I don't understand why the updates queries are not working :(

if I query the context:

```
 curl -s -X GET -H "Accept: text/plain" -H "fiware-service: tourguide" 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f/attrs/capacity/value'
```

I get correctly the value "50"

if I update the value, following the query examples:

```
curl -s -v -X PUT -H "Accept: text/plain" -H "fiware-service: tourguide" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" 'http://160.85.2.22:1026/v2/entities/0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f/attrs/capacity/value' -d 52
```

i get error "The requested entity has not been found. Check type and id"

```
*   Trying 160.85.2.22...
* Connected to 160.85.2.22 (160.85.2.22) port 1026 (#0)
> PUT /v2/entities/0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f/attrs/capacity/value?type=Restaurant HTTP/1.1
> Host: 160.85.2.22:1026
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: application/json
> fiware-service: tourguide
> Content-Type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 2
> 
} [2 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 2 out of 2 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 95
< Content-Type: application/json
< Fiware-Correlator: 9d2f4164-48f3-11e6-af87-0242ac110004
< Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2016 12:16:23 GMT
< 
{ [95 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host 160.85.2.22 left intact
{
    "description": "The requested entity has not been found. Check type and id",
    "error": "NotFound"
}
```

Comment: Could your edit your question to include the Orion version you are using (the output of the commant `contextBroker --version`), please? Thanks!

Comment: it's a docker container (latest and develop give the same issue) using

  `curl -s -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "fiware-service: tourguide" 'http://160.85.2.22:1026/version' | python -m json.tool`
   `{
       "orion": {
           "compile_time": "Thu Jul 14 11:27:13 UTC 2016",
           "compiled_by": "root",
           "compiled_in": "838a42ae8431",
           "git_hash": "85b4106319aaba1837a9805f4f092f78f18a1a20",
           "uptime": "1 d, 22 h, 14 m, 51 s",
           "version": "1.2.0-next"
      }
    }`

Comment: I have done a test based on your case using your same version and in my case and I'm afraid I'm unable to reproduce, i.e. all works as expected in my case. The testing session can be found here: https://gist.github.com/fgalan/0d94fdb3d6de93a88c11ffe93cfab53c. Could you have a look to it trying to identify differences comparing with your case? If you are unable to identify any difference, next step would be trying to reproduce that exact procedure in order to see if you get the same results (use "tourguide2" in order to do the test in a separate service, isolated from "tourguide").

Comment: I have realized that this case is based on the FIWARE Tour Guide applications. There are some considerations to take into account regarding service paths in that case... I have an idea of what can be happending, but let me some time to check it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are using the context data of the [FIWARE Tour Guide Application](https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.TourGuide-App). In that context data, Restaurant entities belong to different [service paths](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/service_path/index.html). In particular, each Resturant belong to a service path corresponding to the value of its `department` attribute.

Thus, have a look to the `department` attribute of the 0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f entity (using the Fiware-Service header: "tourguide"). If the value of the attribute is for example "Franchise4" then you have to use the following service path header in your PUT request (pay attention to the initial `/`):

```
-H "fiware-servicepath: /Franchise4"
```

Why GET request on attribute value is working without service path header while PUT request on attribute value isn't? When the header is omitted, query requests default to `/#` (which means "any service path") while create/udpate requests default to `/` (which is the root service path, which doesn't match with `/Franchise4`).

Comment: FIWARE Tour Guide Application documentation could be improved including the details that I'm expalining in my answer. I have opened an issue at https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.TourGuide-App/issues/120, in the hope FIWARE Tour Guide App can improve it.

Comment: thanks a lot fermin. indeed there was nothing about that in the documentation of the FIWARE Tour Guide Application :) Is there a way to query for all existing service-paths ?

Comment: "Is there a way to query for all existing service-paths?" That deserves a new question at SOF ;)